# node.js cannot read property of "New"

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying to resolve an issue with my Alexa Skill right now. I watched and read a lot of tutorials and tried to search for it, but I always get a cryptic Error Message from Node.js...
I just try to send a http request, so nothing complicated.

My Code looks like this:

```
var https = require('https')

exports.handler = (event, context) => {

  try {

    if (event.session.new) {
      console.log("NEW SESSION")
    }

    switch (event.request.type) {

      case "LaunchRequest":
        console.log(`LAUNCH REQUEST`)
        context.succeed(
          generateResponse(
            buildSpeechletResponse("Willkommen bei Taasker", true),
            {}
          )
        )
        break;

      case "IntentRequest":
        console.log(`INTENT REQUEST`)

        switch(event.request.intent.name) {
          case "taskernightlighton":
            var endpoint = "" 
            var body = ""
            http.request("https://autoremotejoaomgcd.appspot.com/sendmessage?key=xxxxxxxxxxxxx&message=nightlighton")
            context.succeed(
                 generateResponse(
                    buildSpeechletResponse(`Licht wird von Taasker eingeschaltet`, true),
                    {}
                 )
            )
            break;

          case "taskernightlightoff":
            http.request("https://autoremotejoaomgcd.appspot.com/sendmessage?key=xxxxxxxxxx&message=nightlightoff")
            context.succeed(
                 generateResponse(
                    buildSpeechletResponse(`Licht wird von Taasker ausgeschaltet`, true),
                    {}
                 )
            )
            break;

          default:
            throw "Invalid intent"
        }

        break;

      case "SessionEndedRequest":
        console.log(`SESSION ENDED REQUEST`)
        break;

      default:
        context.fail(`INVALID REQUEST TYPE: ${event.request.type}`)

    }

  } catch(error) { context.fail(`Exception: ${error}`) }

}

// Helpers
buildSpeechletResponse = (outputText, shouldEndSession) => {

  return {
    outputSpeech: {
      type: "PlainText",
      text: outputText
    },
    shouldEndSession: shouldEndSession
  }

}

generateResponse = (speechletResponse, sessionAttributes) => {

  return {
    version: "1.0",
    sessionAttributes: sessionAttributes,
    response: speechletResponse
  }

}
```

And I always receive the following error:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Exception: TypeError: Cannot read property 'new' of undefined"
}
```

Can someone give me a hint, what is wrong with my javascript syntax? I cannot find a source explaining this http request? Please help...

Answer (score 2):

I can tell you what the error message means. The error message is not cryptic at all.

```
"Exception: TypeError: Cannot read property 'new' of undefined"
```

Apparently you have an object that has the property `new`. So without reading your code I now know that you have an object that looks something like `myObject.new`. The error is saying that `myObject` is undefined and therefore it cannot access the value in `new` because there is no value. The interpreter looks at it like this:

`var myObject = undefined`

And what you try to do is:

`myObject.new` which basically is viewed by the runtime as `undefined.new`, which is not possible.

**Lets get practical**

When I did CTRL + F in your program I found that you have:

`if (event.session.new) {`

So my guess is as follows: either `event` is undefined or `session` is undefined. That gives the error, which begs the following question: how are you calling the exported `handler`? You might have an issue there.

Another question is: does `console.log` log the `"NEW SESSION"` ?