# Alexa aws lambda function prompting an error when creating a new object

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am starting to learn how to create a lambda function. I wanted to implement a lambda function that can control a led on an arduino uno device. I found [this code](https://github.com/ForceTronics/Arduino_Echo_Home_Automation/blob/master/forceTronicsHomeAuto) on GitHub.

I copied and pasted it and got the following error:

> "errorMessage": "Exception: TypeError: Cannot read property 'new' of
>   undefined".

I searched on StackOverflow and I found [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40834090/node-js-cannot-read-property-of-new) but the answer did not help a lot.

Please I need help in fixing this code. I do not know if it matters but the variable endpoint that contains links for a cloud (sparkfun) is out of service.
Thank you so much for your time and consideration!

Below is the code:

```
var https = require('https'); //include https
var http = require('http');

exports.handler = (event, context) => {

  try {

    if (event.session.new) {
      // New Session
      console.log("NEW SESSION"); //log this for debugging
    }

    switch (event.request.type) {

      case "LaunchRequest":
        // Launch Request
        console.log(`LAUNCH REQUEST`)
        context.succeed(
          generateResponse(
            buildSpeechletResponse("Welcome to the ForceTronics Home Automation Skill, say turn light on or turn light off", true), //response for Alexa if you just call the skill without intent
            {}
          )
        )
        break;

      case "IntentRequest":
        // Intent Request
        console.log(`INTENT REQUEST`)

        switch(event.request.intent.name) { //switch statement to select the right intent
          case "TurnLightOn": //if you told alexa to turn the light on this will be true
          var endpoint = "https://data.sparkfun.com/input/1nlZrX0NbdfwxgrY0zA0?private_key=0mDlvAkdoRIq976eakpa&lightstate=1" //https string to log data to phant phant
          https.get(endpoint, function (result) { //use https get request to send data to phant
          console.log('Success, with: ' + result.statusCode);
          context.succeed(
           generateResponse( //if you succeeded allow Alexa to tell you state of light
                buildSpeechletResponse("The light is turned on", true),
                {}
            )
          )
          }).on('error', function (err) {
            console.log('Error, with: ' + err.message);
            context.done("Failed");
          });
            break;

          case "TurnLightOff": //the turn light off intent
            var endpoint2 = "https://data.sparkfun.com/input/1nlZrX0NbdfwxgrY0zA0?private_key=0mDlvAkdoRIq976eakpa&lightstate=0"; // phant string to set light state to off
            https.get(endpoint2, function (result) {
            console.log('Success, with: ' + result.statusCode);
            context.succeed(
                generateResponse( //Alexa response if successful
                 buildSpeechletResponse("The light is turned off", true),
                    {}
                )
            );
            }).on('error', function (err) {
            console.log('Error, with: ' + err.message);
            context.done("Failed");
            });
            break;

        case "IsWasherRunning": //check the state of the washer
            var endpoint3 = "http://data.sparkfun.com/output/pw8EWVl18zUgW9OYzJNv.csv?page=1"; // phant csv file page

            http.get(endpoint3, function (response) { //http get request, data is returned to response
                response.setEncoding('utf8');
                response.on('data', function (body) { //now let's go through response data from phant cloud
                    //following variables are getting hour and date info to ensure data is new and not old
                    var lHour = Date().substr(16,2); //hour from amazon server
                    var dHour = body.substr(35,2); //hour from phant cloud data
                    var lDate = Date().substr(8,2);
                    var dDate = body.substr(32,2);

                    if(checkTime(lHour, dHour, lDate, dDate)===1) { //if this is true data from phant is fresh
                        var s = body.substr(22,1); //read washer state data from phant string
                        if (s=='1') { //if it is 1 then washer is on
                            context.succeed(
                                generateResponse( //if you succeeded allow Alexa to tell you state of light
                                    buildSpeechletResponse("The washer is running", true),
                                    {}
                                )
                            );
                        }
                        else if (s=='0') { //if it is 0 then washer is off
                            context.succeed(
                            generateResponse( //if you succeeded allow Alexa to tell you state of light
                                buildSpeechletResponse("The washer is off", true),
                                    {}
                                )
                            );
                        }
                        else { //if this is true then there is an issue getting data from phant
                            context.succeed(
                            generateResponse( //if you succeeded allow Alexa to tell you state of light
                                buildSpeechletResponse("There was an error checking washer state", true),
                                    {}
                                )
                            );
                        }
                    }
                    else { //if this is true the data is old and there maybe something wrong with the hardware
                        console.log("didn't pass date and time test");
                        context.succeed(
                        generateResponse( //if you succeeded allow Alexa to tell you state of light
                                buildSpeechletResponse("No recent washer state data available", true),
                                    {}
                            )
                        );
                    }
                });
                response.on('error', console.error);
            });
            break;

          default:
            throw "Invalid intent";
        }

        break;

      case "SessionEndedRequest":
        // Session Ended Request
        console.log(`SESSION ENDED REQUEST`);
        break;

      default:
        context.fail(`INVALID REQUEST TYPE: ${event.request.type}`)

    }

  } catch(error) { context.fail(`Exception: ${error}`) }

}

// builds an Alexa response
buildSpeechletResponse = (outputText, shouldEndSession) => {

  return {
    outputSpeech: {
      type: "PlainText",
      text: outputText
    },
    shouldEndSession: shouldEndSession
  }

};

//plays Alexa reponse
generateResponse = (speechletResponse, sessionAttributes) => {

  return {
    version: "1.0",
    sessionAttributes: sessionAttributes,
    response: speechletResponse
  }

};

//this function checks to see if data from phant cloud is relitively new
function checkTime(lTime, dTime, lDay, dDay) {
    //turn hour and date strings into ints
     var lT = parseInt(lTime);
     var dT = parseInt(dTime);
     var lD = parseInt(lDay);
     var dD = parseInt(dDay);

     if(lD===dD && lT===dT) { //if it is same day and hour then data is good
         return 1;
     }
     else if(lD===dD && (lT - 1)===dT) { //if day is the same and hour is only off by one then data is good
         return 1;
     }
     else if((lD - 1)===dD && lT===0 && dT===23) { //if date is one off but time is around midnight then data is good
         return 1;
     }
     else return 0; //if none of the above if statements are true then data is old
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means the object 'event' (look at your line exports.handler) does not have a key called 'session'.  Everything after that is non consequential until you fix that.  I cannot know what you wanted to accomplish with that call.

Do this:

```
    console.log(event);
```

You can also look up 'event' in the AWS documentation.

Then you can look for whatever you thought 'session' was and move forward from there.  Good luck.  Post details of what you thought 'session' was if you get stuck.  I don't think you need that though.  I can't know for sure from what you posted.